# How can I create a nested object in swagger model

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I have a object like

```
public GenericBO {

   private int id;

   private String code;

   private int parentId;

   private List<GenericBO> child = new ArrayList<GenericBO>();

  //getters and setters respectively
}
```

How can I create the model for the same in swagger?

Comment: Do you write the OpenAPI definition manually or generate it from code?

Comment: I write it from manually, How do I generate from the code?

Comment: Check out [Springfox](https://github.com/springfox/springfox) or [Swagger Core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core). Vladlas Maier's answer below shows how you would annotate the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between annotating nested or not nested Swagger models.

You have to add `io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty` annotation to each attribute of the model.

```
public GenericModel {

   @ApiModelProperty(value = "ID")
   private int id;

   @ApiModelProperty(value = "Code")
   private String code;

   @ApiModelProperty(value = "Parent Id")
   private int parentId;

   @ApiModelProperty(value = "Children")
   private List<GenericModel> children = new ArrayList<>();

   ...
}
```

If the list object is a collection of other models you must annotate the corresponding model (with `@ApiModelProperty` annotations) as well.